# Shiny app only partially working on Shiny Server

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to shiny and have written my first app to plot some graphs based on some health data.  The app works as I imagined locally but when I deployed it on shinyapps.io, I am only getting a plot on the third tab (which works fine).  However, plots on the first 2 tab failed to give me anything even though the data it needs come from the same file that I've also uploaded.

Is there something obvious that I've missed or done to generate the first 3 plots that means it would not give me anything?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)


ERAS <- readRDS("ERAS.rda")

ERAS_yearly <- ERAS %>% 
  arrange(year_m) %>% 
  mutate(DoSdate = ymd(year_m), yearDoS = year(DoSdate), monthDoS = month(DoSdate)) %>%
  group_by(yearDoS) %>%
  summarise(year_meanLOS = mean(Postop_LOS),
            year_meanAll3 = mean(All_3 == T, na.rm = T),
            year_AKI = mean(AKI_pos == T, na.rm = T))

# User Interface

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("NERCI Data"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      print("Choose the following for graphs on Tabs 1 and 2:"),

      sliderInput("year", "Select Year:", animate = T,
                            min = 2016, max = 2019, value = 2016, sep = ""),

      checkboxGroupInput("approach", "Surgical Approach", c("Laparoscopic", "Lap-assisted", "Converted to open", "Open"),
                       selected = c("Laparoscopic", "Lap-assisted", "Converted to open", "Open")),

      print("Choose the following for graph on Tab 3:"),

      selectInput("x_axis", "Choose x axis",
                  c("Surgical Risk" = "Risk", 
                     "Obesity Class" = "Obesity", 
                     "ASA-PS" = "ASA",
                     "Anaemia" = "Anaemia",
                     "Acute Kidney Injury" = "AKI_pos",
                     "DrEaming Goals" = "All_3",
                     "Surgical Approach" = "Sx_Approach",
                     "POMS on Day 3" = "posPOMS3",
                     "POMS on Day 5" = "posPOMS5",
                     "Re-operation for Leaks" = "Reoperation_Leak",
                     "Re-operation for Other" = "Reoperation_Other",
                     "ICU Admission" = "ICU_Admission"),
                   selected = "Surgical Risk"),

      selectInput("y_axis", "Choose y axis", 
                 c("Total Post-op Length of Stay" = "Postop_LOS",
                     "SHDU Length of Stay" = "HDU_LOS")),

      selectInput("extra_filter", "Choose additional info",
                 c("Surgical Approach" = "Sx_Approach",
                   "Surgical Risk" = "Risk",
                   "Obesity Class" = "Obesity"),
                 selected = "Surgical Approach"),

      dateRangeInput("date", "Choose Date Range of Data to display",
                     start = "2016-02-01", end = Sys.Date(),
                     min = "2016-02-01", max = Sys.Date())

                      ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("DrEaMing", 
                 plotOutput(outputId = "LOS_plot"),
                 plotOutput(outputId = "All3_plot")),

        tabPanel("AKI Data",
                 plotOutput(outputId = "AKI_plot")),

        tabPanel("Length of Stay Data",
                plotOutput(outputId = "LOS_overall"))
      )
    )
  )
)

# Server

server <- function(input, output){

  output$LOS_plot <- renderPlot({

    plot1a <- ERAS %>% filter(Sx_Approach %in% input$approach) %>% 
      arrange(year_m) %>% 
      mutate(DoSdate = ymd(year_m), yearDoS = year(DoSdate), monthDoS = month(DoSdate)) %>% 
      filter(yearDoS == input$year) %>%
      group_by(year_m) %>%
      mutate(mean_LOS = mean(Postop_LOS)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = monthDoS, y = mean_LOS)) + geom_line(colour = "#A8659C", size = 1.5) +
      geom_hline(data = ERAS_yearly[ERAS_yearly$yearDoS == input$year, ], aes(yintercept = year_meanLOS), alpha = 0.4, colour = "#323232") + 
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 12), breaks = c(1:12)) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,30), minor_breaks = 1) +
      theme(aspect.ratio = 0.4) + xlab("Month") + ylab("Days") + ggtitle("Mean Length of Stay over Time")

    plot1a

  })
  output$All3_plot <- renderPlot({

    plot1b <- ERAS %>% filter(Sx_Approach %in% input$approach) %>%
      arrange(year_m) %>% 
      mutate(DoSdate = ymd(year_m), yearDoS = year(DoSdate), monthDoS = month(DoSdate)) %>% 
      filter(yearDoS == input$year) %>% group_by(year_m) %>%
      mutate(mean_All3 = mean(All_3 == T, na.rm = T)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = monthDoS, y = mean_All3)) + geom_line(colour = "#116133", size = 1.5) + 
      geom_hline(data = ERAS_yearly[ERAS_yearly$yearDoS == input$year, ], aes(yintercept = year_meanAll3), alpha = 0.4, colour = "#323232") +
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 12), breaks = c(1:12)) +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, limits = c(0, 1)) +
      theme(aspect.ratio = 0.4) + xlab("Month") + ylab("Percentage") + ggtitle("Patients Achieving All Three ERAS Goals")

    plot1b

  })
  output$AKI_plot <- renderPlot({

    plot2 <- ERAS %>% filter(Sx_Approach %in% input$approach) %>%
      arrange(year_m) %>% 
      mutate(DoSdate = ymd(year_m), yearDoS = year(DoSdate), monthDoS = month(DoSdate)) %>% 
      filter(yearDoS == input$year) %>% group_by(year_m) %>%
      mutate(mean_AKI = mean(AKI_pos == T, na.rm = T)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = monthDoS, y = mean_AKI)) + geom_line(colour = "#FDDB2E", size = 1.5) + 
      geom_hline(data = ERAS_yearly[ERAS_yearly$yearDoS == input$year, ], aes(yintercept = year_AKI), alpha = 0.4, colour = "#323232") +
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 12), breaks = c(1:12)) +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, limits = c(0, 1)) +
      theme(aspect.ratio = 0.4) + xlab("Month") + ylab("Percentage") + ggtitle("Percentage of Patients with Post-op AKI")

    plot2

  })
  output$LOS_overall <- renderPlot({
    x <- input$x_axis
    y <- input$y_axis
    extra <- input$extra_filter

    ERAS <- filter(ERAS, DoS >= input$date[1] & DoS <= input$date[2])

    plot03 <- ggplot(data = ERAS, aes_string(x = x, y = y)) + 
      geom_jitter(aes_string(colour = extra), alpha = 0.5, size = 5) +
      geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.5) +
      ggtitle("Length of Stay Post-op") + xlab(x) + ylab("Length of Stay") +
      theme(aspect.ratio = 0.6)

    plot03

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Start by checking that all packages and R versions are the same.

Comment: Probably really rudimentary but how do I go about doing this?  Sorry, still new to this

Comment: Use sessionInfo()

Comment: Sorry to ask you to spell it out for me, but how will I check it against the server version and then what I can do from there if that is the problem?

Comment: Not to sure about how to check it on shinyapps.io but I'm sure you can do some googling to understand how packages are managed in shinyapps.io. IF they are different, I would upgrade (or downgrade) the versions to match.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look